# Can't install ubuntu on dell inspiron 3670 - i5

Tags: system-installation, inspiron

I just got a brand new desktop a dell inspiron 3670 i5 with a ssd. Im having a real hard time installing ubuntu. Tried making a USB of 18.04lts and that failed on multiple levels to install. I created a 40gb partition in windows 10 disk management but its ntfs or exFAT only no option for ext4. The ubuntu installer isn't giving me any options for install alongside windows. I have fast boot and secure boot turned off in bios. I am now trying to install from a dvd of 18.04 and i keep getting a message that ubuntu requires atleast 29 gb of free space and this computer has 0 bytes available. For some reason its not seeing the hard drive. Even when i try ubuntu and run gparted it only sees the dvd. Ive spent many frustrating hours on this and need help please!

---

[image]

Ive got a 39gb unallocated partition, no volume.  I never get to the point in the installer where I can chose partitions to install to, all I get is the 0 bytes available message after choosing my network.  Ive tried this with 18.04lts and 19.04 as well.

Comment: The Ubuntu installer will make a partition for you. There's no need to use Windows Disk Management to do that, especially since you can't create ext4 or other preferred Linux partitions.  - gparted has a drive selection spinbox at upper right; please make sure you are selecting the HDD or SSD and not the optical drive.

Comment: please add screenshots of gparted if possible. `For some reason its not seeing the hard drive`

Comment: Check your BIOS.  WIn10 preinstalled systems usually use RAID+ACHI mode and that doesn't work really well with *buntu

Comment: Dell normally needs UEFI update & SSD firmware update even if new. And drive(s) set to AHCI. But you first need to install AHCI driver into Windows or turn RAID back on to allow Windows to boot. And then in Windows turn off fast start up. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi Be sure to fully backup Windows. Dell  Inspiron 3670 UEFI update & AHCI worked
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2412152

Comment: I just bought a Lenovo IdeaPad S340-15/WL Touch with the same thing happening.  I tried with installers for 19.10 as well as 18, in 19 I get the installer seeing the USB drive in the "Installation type" window but not the internal laptop drive, and in 18 it sees neither.  I have left the free space unallocated.  Not sure how to set my drive to AHCI (if required), any more detailed instructions on that?

Answer (score 0):

from windows, you can't create ext4 partition, so just create a partition and delete the volume, leave it as free space.

keep in mind if you create the partition from GParted(using live ubuntu) and for some reason, you fail to install ubuntu, you won't be able to boot windows, because windows boot loader won't boot. So for safety create the partition in windows and delete the volume.

now boot from your bootable thumb-drive/DVD and install ubuntu. Select free space and create a partition for root(/) from free space and a partition for swap(if you need).

If you have enough ram, you can skip the swap part and use the entire free space for the root partition (just select the partition and choose mount point `/` and format as ext4) and continue. SIMPLE

If you've only one disk, select the primary disk for boot loader (grub) installation, grub will detect and add an entry for the windows and you'll be able to boot both ubuntu as well as windows from grub.

If you've 2 disks you can choose to install ubuntu on a different disk which will be cleaner install, but you have to choose which disk you want to use as a default boot disk, you can set that up in your bios, and when you want to boot from a different disk, you've to go through choose boot device every time.

Please comment if you have any questions or doubts.